# How can I display 3 posts in slider for whole day and changes on next day randomly in laravel 5.5?

Tags: random, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel. I am creating a blog. In the homepage, I have a slider where I want to put 3 posts randomly for single day and changes on next day. For now I am using "random(3);" query as you can see in controller which gives record randomly.

The problem is I want posts for the whole day and in this method the posts changes every time the page refreshes. So, How can I do this? Please give me suggestion...

My codes are below. Thanks in advance...

HomeController file:

```html
    public function homepage()
        {
            $randomPost = Post::all()->random(3);

            return view('user/pages/homepage',compact('randomPost'));
        }
```

homepage.blade.php file:

```html
    <div id="main-slider" class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">
            @foreach ($randomPost as $post)
                <li><a href="{{ URL::route('post', $post->slug) }}">
                    <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="{{ Storage::disk('local')->url($post->image) }}" alt="" />
                    <div class="flex-caption">
                        <h3 style="color: #FFF; font-size:35px;"><b>{{ $post->title }}</b></h3>
                    </div></a>
                </li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved,

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;

...

public function homepage()
{
    $randomPost = Cache::remember('randomPost', 60*24, function () {
        return Post::inRandomOrder()->take(3)->get();
    });

    return view('user/pages/homepage',compact('randomPost'));
}
```

at

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-can-i-display-3-posts-in-slider-for-whole-day-and-changes-on-next-day-randomly-in-laravel-55

Answer (score 0):

Use Carbon and the whereDate method:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

public function homepage()
{
    $randomPost = Post::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'))->get()->random(3);

    return view('user/pages/homepage', compact('randomPost'));
}
```

Comment: 'Posts of the day' is title for slider. Actually I want to display 3 random posts from starting  date. likewise in Wikipedia homepage we see "Today's Featured Article". Sorry for my bad representation of question